# mic check term: "It is fine today"

Tags: obscure-terms

There's a term in Japanese:

[本日は晴天なり](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AC%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF%E6%99%B4%E5%A4%A9%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A)

which apparently comes from English

> 英語のマイクテスト時の言葉"It is fine today"の直訳。英語の文言は、音素が一通り出てくるため用いられているが、日本語のものにはその機能は無い。
>
> Tr (by Google): A literal translation of the word "It is fine today" in the English microphone test. English phrases are used because phonemes come out one by one, but those in Japanese do not have that function.

The idea is that when doing a mic check in English people would say: `It is fine today` (as in: weather wise) and this term subsequently got directly translated (and used) in Japanese in the same manner.

I have never heard `It is fine today` used as a "mic check term" in English.

Is this an actual thing in English? or just a misunderstanding?

Is there any proof to this actually being used in English?

Comment: The usual mic check in the US is "check one two, check one two, ..." It has no meaning AFAIK, just something to say that doesn't make people think you are unaware the mic is live.

Comment: In India we say either "mike testing" or "hello...hello" to check the mic. 'It is fine today' seems to be just a neutral comment to check that the mic is working properly. [Humorous interpretation: if the sound system has been inconsistent recently, it could mean *thank my stars -- it's (working) fine today!*]

Comment: I've added the explanation in English. I'm not sure about the last phrase: perhaps it should be something like "do not work that way" or something.

Comment: I've also never heard it, or anything that sounds like it. "Check one, check two" and "Testing, 1-2-3" are the common phrases in the US.

Comment: I think this belongs on Japanese SE, not English.

Comment: I'm confused by two things in this question: 1) The translation suggests that Japanese phonemes do not come out one by one. Do they come out simultaneously, then? How would that work? 2) The Japanese translation would still be in Japanese, so what pronunciation advantages would that have over the English version?

Comment: The question is just asking if, "It is fine today," is a known phrase used when performing a "mic check."

Answer (score 1):

I found "[本日は晴天なり](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%84%A1%E7%B7%9A%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E#.E7.84.A1.E7.B7.9A.E9.9B.BB.E8.A9.B1.E7.94.A8)=vvv" in Japanese radio code, and didn't find it in English radio code. It might be used in weather report of U.S. Coast Guard.